# ora-12541: tns no listener error and lsnrctl still work on 1521

Tags: oracle

I have tried all day to fix ora-12541 issue on my aix vm. Have checked hostname, listener.ora, tnsname.ora but still no luck with the issue.
Not sure what's wrong with my configuration.
And also very confused that I have configured port 2931 on listener.ora but when running "lsnrctl status",it showed listening on 1521 and I only have one listener configured.
Can you give me a hand on how to fix ora-12541 and above questions? Thanks a lot.

[image: etc/hosts file]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show also `lsnrctl services`, `tnsping {dbname}` and your tnsnames.ora

Comment: do you have 2 different listeners? did you restart listener? show us please the result of this command: `lsnrctl stop && lsnrctl start && lsnrctl status && lsnrctl services`

Comment: Why are you even _trying_ to configure your listener on a non-default port (default is 1521). If this is "for security", it would take a hacker about 2 nano-seconds to break it.  Also there is no reason to run a listener with a non-default name. None. Your best bet would be to simply remove your listener.ora and restart your listener. It will happily start with all default values, which will mesh nicely with everything else and should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the listener configured in the listener.ora is "listener_ow***". By default if no listener is specified in the lsnrctl, a listener with a name of "listener" is assumed.  Since no "listener" is configured the port 1521 is used by the lsnrctl.

Based on your configuration you start your listener with "lsnrctl start listener_ow***" and check the status with "lsnrctl status listener_ow***".

Your need to change "SID_LIST_LISTENER" parameter in your listener.ora to "SID_LIST_LISTENER_OW***" to match the listener you named in the listener.ora.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated the listener.ora file as you suggested and stop/start lnsrctl.  Now when using sqlplus sys/test@OW**** as sysdba, it threw ora-01017 error "invalid username/password" and I am sure the username/password is correct.  How can I handle this error?

Comment: Please verify your configured listener is serving the database specified with the OW**** TNS alias configured in the TNSNAMES.ORA, assuming you are using TNSNAMES.ORA.